# How can I consume web services in Android?

Tags: android, web-services, soap, consuming

I want to consume soap web services from an Android Application. I am using `ksoap2`, but I am not getting the output. Please tell me alternate way to consume web services from an Android Application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

User HttpPost or HttpGet Request its up-to your requirement.